# Merging NSArrays in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

I have an NSDictionary where each key points to an array. I later want to merge all of the values into one array. Is there a way to use the API to do something more efficient than say:

```
NSArray *anArray = [someDictionary allValues];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
start outter loop on anArray
   start inner loop on objects in anArray
     add objectAtIndex to newArray
```

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/q/8569388/78336

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just use `[newArray addObjectsFromArray:anArray];`

Comment: Hi Ben, If I do it this way I don't have a flat array. I have an array of arrays. I was seeing if it was possible to do it without the looping.

Comment: This should still give you a flat array; you're not adding the array, you're adding the objects FROM the array.

Comment: Coocoo4Cocoa: I think you've confused `addObject`**`FromArray:`** with `addObject:`. `addObject:` adds *the array* to the new array, whereas what Chuck and Ben Gottlieb have suggested adds the elements in the array to the new array.

Answer (score 21):

[`-[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablearray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray:)

Comment: I'm glad someone pointed out the class type. I'd sat there for a second wondering why the method wasn't being auto-completed.

Answer (score 20):

There is some confusion in Benn Gottlieb's answer above. To clarify, he is suggesting using **addObjectsFromArray** instead of the inner loop, whereas Coocoo is confused because he thinks it is being suggested as a replacement for ALL the looping. (If you do this, you will indeed be left with an unflattened array of arrays as per his objection.)

Here is a reasonably elegant solution that doesn't require any explicit looping:

```
NSArray *anArray = [someDictionary allValues];
NSArray *flattenedArray = [anArray valueForKeyPath: @"@unionOfArrays.self"];
```

btw this code will leave duplicates in the flattened array. If you want to remove duplicates, use **distinctUnionOfArrays** instead of **unionOfArrays**.

Comment: Today, this is a better solution than all of the above.