# NSArray of united Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have an NSArray of objects called MMPlace, which has NSArray of MMProduct objects.

How do I get a united NSArray of all MMProduct objects that my Array of MMPlace object contains? Something like `NSArray *arr = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.products"];` would be nice, though this specific example doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an NSMutableArray, loop through your original array and call `addObjectsFromArray:` with each subarray.

Answer (score 43):

You can do this with `@unionOfArrays`.  The bit you were missing is that because the arrays are directly nested, the key on the right of the collection operator must be `self`:

```
NSArray *nestedValues = @[@[@1, @2, @3], @[@4, @5, @6]]
NSArray *flattenedValues = [nestedValues valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
// flattenedValues contains @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an off-the-shelf method that does what you need, but you can easily "flatten" your array in a `for` loop, and hide the method in a category:

Edit: added a category.

```
@interface NSArray (flatten)
    -(NSArray*) flattenArray;
@end

@implementation NSArray (flatten)
-(NSArray*) flattenArray {
    // If inner array has N objects on average, multiply count by N
    NSMutableArray *res = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.count];
    for (NSArray *element in self) {
        [res addObjectsFromArray:element];
    }
    return res;
}
@end
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to evade. Guess there's no real choice. :(

Comment: You can add an implementation to a category of `NSArray`, and hide it from your sight behind a nice little method.

Answer (score 1):

For this task there is the @unionOfArrays collection operator.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implemented a "flatten" category method that will work on any tree structure. It will take a tree of arbitrary depth and merge it into one long array in order.

```
- (NSArray *) flattenWithBlock:(NSArray *(^)(id obj))block {
    NSMutableArray *newItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(id subObject in self)
    {
        if([subObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            [newItems addObjectsFromArray:[subObject flatten:block]];
        }
        else
            [newItems addObject:subObject];
    }

    return newItems;
}
```

You could then write a convenience category method which handles the case you described above. This wrapper method will flatten a nd array into a 1d array.

```
- (NSArray *) flattenArray {
    NSArray *newItems = [self flattenWithBlock:^NSArray *(id obj) {
        return obj;
    }];

    return newItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface NSArray (Flatten)

-(NSArray*)flattenedArray;

@end

@implementation NSArray (Flatten)

-(NSArray*)flattenedArray {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.count];
    for (id thing in self) {
        if ([thing isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [result addObjectsFromArray:[(NSArray*)thing flattenedArray]];
        } else {
            [result addObject:thing];
        }
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];
}

@end
```